# How to provision salesforce prmission sets using okta?

Tags: salesforce, provisioning, okta

I'd like to have multiple salesforce "apps" in okta, each configured with provisioning.  There will be a "base" one which actually provisions the base salesforce account.  But then I want additional salesforce "apps" configured in okta which just provision (or remove) additional permission sets - adding or removing permission sets to the base account.  These permission sets represent granting or revoking access to custom force.com apps hosted in the same salesforce org.

I have tried doing this using the following mapping:

```
Okta User Profile / user
  Arrays.add(salesforce_1.publicGroups,'My perm set')
```

maps to:

```
Salesforce.com (add my perm set) / appuser
  salesforceGroups
```

the idea being that the above would just add the "my perm set" permission set to whatever permission sets the salesforce account already has.

but its giving me the following error:

```
Unable to resolve salesforce_1 in expression Arrays.add(salesforce_1.publicGroups,
'My perm set'). Attributes from the same profile cannot be mapped to each other.
```

I'm also not seeing where I would have the opportunity to configure the deprovisioning logic... which would be:

```
Arrays.remove(salesforce_1.publicGroups,'My perm set')
```

Is there any way to achieve what i'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

The provisioning in Okta is tied to a named account in SFDC.  What you are trying to do will not work because each SFDC app in Okta will provision or deprovision the actual SFDC account of the user.  You can't really split things up as you've intended within Okta.

You will need to rely on updating the user profile in a single okta app instance - keeping track of the consolidated permissions needed each time you update the user to make sure "all the permissions" governing "all the custom force apps" are captured.